# Java JPA: create JPA queries dynamically based on permissions

Tags: java, jpa, authorization, abac

We have the following problem:
we have 2 different user groups, that can form consents and a method (e.g. `getAllValues()`) should only return the values the user has access to.

Each value has a timestamp and each consent has a beginning and an end time.

In the case above, the current user should get all values of all users he has a consent with. Additionally he should only receive the values in the timespan of the consent.

#### Example

User A has consent with user B from `2000-01-01` to `2000-01-31`. User B has values at `1999-12-15`, `2000-01-15`, `2000-02-15`. User A should only receive the value at 2000-01-15 when `getAllValues()` is invoked.

We have already found a way to write long SQL-statements that do exactly that, but they are hard to read and maintain. Now we're looking for a better way to use Shiro or another permission framework in combination with JPA/Hibernate.

What we don't want is to query all values and check them afterwards since this would create a large overhead.

But so far our only solution is to write very complex JPQL-statements to achieve this.

Comment: if you're using `Spring` probably `AOP` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use an externalized authorization framework e.g. Apache Shiro, Spring Security, or Axiomatics Policy Server.

What you are really looking for is attribute-based access control where you can define what users can do in terms of their attributes (including role), attributes of the object or resource, the action, and attributes of the context (time, date, location...).

The latter is what matters to you the most.

Your requirement is:

> In the case above, the current user should get all values of all users he has a consent with. Additionally he should only receive the values in the timespan of the consent.

In ALFA, the Abbreviated Language For Authorization, the requirement becomes the following rule:

```
 policy consentAccess{
     target clause com.acme.action.actionId=="view" and com.acme.object.objectType=="consent"
     apply firstApplicable
     rule allowUsers{
         permit
         condition com.acme.consent.date==com.acme.allowedConsents.date
     }
 }
```

This policy can then be converted dynamically into a SQL filter by the Axiomatics Data Access Filter. This means you no longer need to muck around SQL or understand how to write a query.

HTH